# Play: How to render before and after a job

Tags: java, playframework, jobs

I have a Play app that compiles some code behind the scenes and I was wondering what the best strategy was to first render a "please wait..." message before the job starts and then a "job complete" message once it is finished.

It's not something that can be chunked, it's either done or not, so I'm guessing without using websockets the only way is to poll with ajax?

thanks!

Comment: There is a [Pusher Play Framework module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/pusher) which you could use to push updates on progress of the long running job over a WebSocket connection to your client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When executing a Job (using `.now()`), it returns a Promise object. Using this, you can use the play `await` function and ajax (long polling) or web sockets.

So, you would do the following

1. display the please wait page
2. make your ajax call that executes the job, and awaits for the job to complete
3. when your ajax returns you simply update the page, whether that is a javascript update to a div, or a redirect to a new page.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Ajax is a good technique for this, but you don't need to poll.

Send an Ajax request and at the same time display "please wait...", then when the response arrives, display "job complete". And yes, you should do long-running tasks in a "play job", so you don't block the thread too long.